# Update queries in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, teradata, oledb, powerquery

I have a query (**Query1**) loaded into **Excel** by using a connection from **Teradata**. Normally when I want to update the query, I have to right click it and choose edit.

[image]

Once inside the **Power Query Editor**, I can open the **Source** and edit the **SQL script** inside to update the query.

[image]

The question is how can I edit this **SQL script** using **VBA**?

Upon trying to use the **Macro Recorder**, I can only refresh the query using

```
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - Query1").OLEDBConnection.Refresh
```

An attempt to edit the **CommandText** also failed. Here is the properties of the query.

[image]

Comment: Did you try using the macro recorder?

Comment: @BigBen I updated the question. I can only refresh the query. Further actions in the Power Query Editor are not recorded.

Comment: Your post isn't exactly clear about specifically what "update the query" stands for. Are you trying to add/replace steps to the PQ query, or you're trying to change the actual SQL `SELECT` statement for it?

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon I'm trying to change the actual SQL SELECT statement when I initially created Query1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First we get the query's formula using:

```
Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Queries.Item("Query1").Formula
```

The reason we need to do this is because the formula string contains some extra information about our database connection and not just a sql query itself. It may look something like this:

```
let Source = Teradata.Database("tdprod1.ov.de", [HierarchicalNavigation=true, Query="SELECT week, revenue FROM table1"]); in Source
```

To update the query, we set `ThisWorkbook.Queries.Item("Query1").Formula` to the new formula string. Also be careful while handling the double quotes inside VBA. Here is the script I used:

```
' Update the query Query1 using the provided parameters
Sub UpdateQuery1()

' string to represent a single double quote for VBA string
Const vbDoubleQuote As String = """"

Dim oledb As OLEDBConnection
Dim queryFormula As String

' get the connection
Set oledb = ThisWorkbook.Connections("Query - Query1").OLEDBConnection

' the new formula of the query
Let queryFormula = _
"let " & _
    "Source = Teradata.Database(" & vbDoubleQuote & "tdprod1.ov.de" & vbDoubleQuote & ", [HierarchicalNavigation=true, Query=" & vbDoubleQuote & _
    "SELECT #(lf)a.kw MOD 100 AS KW, #(lf)a.r_Category2_ID AS Category_ID,#(lf)a.r_category3_ID AS Subcategory_ID,#(lf)#(lf)a.vt_p_j AS VP_Jahr,#(lf)a.vt_p_p AS ..." & _
"in Source"

' update the formula of the query
Let ThisWorkbook.Queries.Item("Query1").Formula = queryFormula

' refresh the connection
oledb.Refresh

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - Query1").OLEDBConnection.Refresh
> ```

First, replace `ActiveWorkbook` with `ThisWorkbook`, since you mean to be working with *that* specific workbook (the one hosting your VBA code), not *whatever workbook happens to be currently active*.

`.Refresh` is a *method* of the OLEDB connection you want to modify: you already have a reference to the connection you want to modify the command text for - all you need is to invoke a method other than `.Refresh` against it, i.e. *try* typing that dot and see what that object has to offer.

You can get the *command text* for that `OLEDBConnection` object through its `CommandText` property - try typing this in the *immediate pane* (Ctrl+G) and see if you get the same output:

```
?ThisWorkbook.Connections("Query - Query1").OLEDBConnection.CommandText
SELECT * FROM [Query1]
```

Just *assign* to that property:

```
Dim oledb As OLEDBConnection
Set oledb = ThisWorkbook.Connections("Query - Query1").OLEDBConnection
oledb.CommandText = "SomeOtherTable"
oledb.Refresh
```

Comment: How can I change the actual `SELECT` statement for Query1? Like instead of `SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE week = 4` to `SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE week = 5` using VBA and not the Power Query Editor. Due to the huge amount of data, I can only query a subset of the data.

Comment: Set the `CommandString` to whatever SELECT query you need, then refresh... as shown above.

Comment: I've tried that but failed as the `CommandType` as you can see in the picture is Table Collection (`xlCmdTable`).

Comment: With Power Query, ThisWorkbook.Queries.("Query - Query1").Formula should contain the corresponding M code. The actual SQL request text is generated on the fly.